# How would one use preg_replace and obtaining matches too?

Tags: php, regex

I have a text that contains usernames prepended with @ symbol. Example:

```
One day @john decided to ask @jane out.
```

I want to replace all occurances of the usernames with a link, for the sake of an example lets say I would want to replace @user with link-user, Example:

```
One day link-john decided to ask link-jane out.
```

This can be done with following command:

```
preg_replace('`@([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15})`', 'link-$1', $text);
```

Additionally I would like to obtain an array of all the matches like preg_match would have done, but I am unable to, because preg_replace does not seem to provide that array. What is the most efficient way to accomplish this? I feel like doing preg_match and later preg_replace would be a waste of resources, would it not?

If you feel there is a better way to accomplish this, I would appreciate your feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't a better option. You could use `preg_replace_callback` to replace and assemble the matches in a callback. But that doesn't qualify as "better" really. -- Regarding resources, always optimize *after* profiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
<pre>
<?php

$arr = array();

function linker( $matches ) {
    global $arr;
    $arr[] = $matches[1];
    return "link-{$matches[1]}";
}

$text = "One day @john decided to ask @jane out.";
$result = preg_replace_callback('`@([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15})`', "linker", $text);

echo $result . "\n";    
print_r( $arr );
?>
</pre>
```

Result:

```
One day link-john decided to ask link-jane out.
Array
(
    [0] => john
    [1] => jane
)
```

If you are using PHP 5.3, you can make this much cleaner with anonymous functions.

Comment: By cleaner you mean I would not have to use global $arr; ?

Comment: @Leo yes if you have php 5.3, definitely use anonymous function like the other answer has. I posted this version cos I wasn't sure you had 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

And another variant of preg_replace_callback utilizing modern 5.3 syntax:

```
$str = "One day @john decided to ask @jane out.";

$matches = array();
$str = preg_replace_callback('`@([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,15})`', function($m) use(&$matches) {
    $matches[] = $m;
    return $m[1] . '-link';
}, $str);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($matches); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @john
            [1] => john
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => @jane
            [1] => jane
        )

)
```

Comment: Would this verion be more favourable since I would not need to use global declaration "global $arr;" ?

Comment: Sure, using `global` is pretty old-school style. PHP 5.3 gives us new oppotunities. Although using global is another way. You decide what appropriate for you.